# How to send map coordinates to javascript file - with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a contact page. This page contains map information. This map is generated by the script file. How do I change the coordinates dynamically? 
Js file content;

```
    var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'style_KINESB';

function initialize() {
  var featureOpts = [
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#666666"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    "featureType": 'all',
    "elementType": 'labels',
    "stylers": [
            { visibility: 'simplified' }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#e2e2e2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#aadaff"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    }
];
  var myGent = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6946703,-73.9280182);
  var Kine = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6946703,-73.9280182);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: myGent
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);  
  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'style_KINESB'
  };

var image = 'images/resource/mapmarker.png';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: Kine,
      map: map,
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: 'B4318, Gumfreston SA70 8RA, United Kingdom',
icon: image
  });

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The area I want to access through the Laravel blade. I want to make the coordinates dynamic.

```
var myGent = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6946703,-73.9280182);
var Kine = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6946703,-73.9280182);
```

contact.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.frontend.master')

@section('title', 'Empathy - Become Volunteer')

@section('content')

@endsection
```

Please help me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What do you send to the view?

Comment: $contact_info = Contact::first();

Comment: And what do you have in `$contact_info`? I mean the coordinates' column names.

Comment: I want to use $contact_info->coordinates(); table column coordinates= "40.6946703,-73.9280182"

Comment: What's the `coordinates` column type? Is it `string(varchar)`?

Comment: Yes string type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205348/discussion-between-rouhollah-mazarei-and-ufuk).

Answer (score 0):

My solution here. I also worked. I'm waiting if you have better solutions.
Firstly. I am add @yield("javascript") directive in master.blade.php file. I add on to the js file.

```
@yield('javascript')
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAAz77U5XQuEME6TpftaMdX0bBelQxXRlM&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('empathy/frontend/assets/js/googlemaps1.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Custom script for all page -->
<script src="{{ asset('empathy/frontend/assets/js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

Later edit contact.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.frontend.master')

@section('title', 'Empathy - Become Volunteer')

@section('content')

@endsection

@section('javascript')
    <script>
        var x = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($coordinate_array[0]) !!}');
        var y = JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($coordinate_array[1]) !!}');
    </script>
@endsection
```

ContactPageController.php

```
$contact = Contact::first();
        $coordinate_array = explode(',', $contact->coordinates); // 40.6946703,-73.9280182
```

This way my solution worked.